# Magento 2 : How to save value of custom attribute defined in customer registration form in frontend?

Tags: magento2, frontend, custom-attributes

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Pulsestorm\NewModule\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'code', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'code',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'code')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','checkout_register','customer_account_edit'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

**customer_account_create.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my_form_additional_info_customer" template="Pulsestorm_NewModule::customer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
 </body>
</page>
```

**customer.phtml**

```
 <fieldset class="fieldset create account" >
        <legend class="legend">
          <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span>
        </legend>
        <p>
        <div class="field regulation required">
          <label for="code" class="label">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Code') ?></span>
          </label>
          <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="regulation" id="code" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Code') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
          </div>
        </div>
        </p>
  </fieldset>
```

Attribute showing at backend and frontend, from backend value is saving (customer create page) but not from frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="regulation" id="code" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Code') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
```

change name "regulation" to "code"